Linux on KUKA controller KR C4/5
I need to configure my RSI interface on the KUKA controller C4. I was following this guide :
https://github.com/ros-industrial/kuka_experimental/tree/melodic-devel/kuka_rsi_hw_interface/krl/KR_C4
and I noticed that the controller run with Windows while my PC with ROS runs on Ubuntu. Is this a problem? How do I solve such situation? Can I install Linux on the controller?
I am new to the whole industrial robotic world and I still have a lot to figure out and understand.

From the first line of the readme in the repo that you link to:

Make sure that the Windows interface of the controller and the PC with ROS is connected to the same subnet.

So, assuming that Windows and Ubuntu are running concurrently, and are indeed on the same subnet, then there shouldn't be any issue.
The networking details are also provided in the readme. If you follow them, then it should (hopefully) work.

As the controller appears to have been written specifically for Windows, then there doesn't seem to be any point in (as you say) "installing Linux on the controller", as it is a Windows specific binary, and (as such) it wouldn't run anyway.
